# Basic website looks weird debugging html/css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am trying to reproduce a very basic Twitter like Rails application that I did sometime ago during a class. I just added Twitter bootstrap, but the top navigation buttons disappear if I run the website locally, and the styling completely disappear if I deploy. No matter where I looked, I could not find how it was different from what I wrote before or where this current code went wrong.

I used latest rails and bootstrap compared to one year ago.

- What I expect to see: http://curails-xl454.herokuapp .com/
- what I actually see locally: if you run this website locally
- what I actually see on heroku: http://cornellblog.herokuapp .com/

My current code can be found here: https://github.com/lukexuanliu/CornellBlog

Comment: Have a look at the dev console, none of your css/js can be found. Also next time you ask a question please make sure you actually have a question instead of "debug this for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Precompile**

The core of the issue is likely going to be the Rails [precompilation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) process, a major issue for new Heroku devs:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.
>
> During the precompilation phase an MD5 is generated from the contents
>   of the compiled files, and inserted into the filenames as they are
>   written to disc. These fingerprinted names are used by the Rails
>   helpers in place of the manifest name.

As your Rails app thinks, by being on Heroku, that it's running in "production" mode. Although programmatically, this does not mean anything different, it *does* have consequences for your environment; specifically that your assets need to be precompiled, and your flow needs to be battle tested (no bugs)

Bottom line is that your `production` assets are not loading because they have not been precompiled correctly (if at all). Your first port of call, therefore, will be to use the following:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Precompiled"
$ git push heroku master
```

If you do this locally, you'll definintely know the assets are precompiled for when you deploy to Heroku, which will eliminate this issue from the potential bugs your system has.

This is further seen to be the case as can be seen by the lack of assets:

[image]

---

**Assets**

In regards to how your application is behaving in development, I would suggest that you either don't have the correct references to the `bootstrap` theme, or you have some sort of issue preventing it from loading.

You'll want to look into [`manifest`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) directives of Rails - basically how you're able to concatenate any of the files you have into a single "application" file -- which will then pull the other "dependent" files into the system.

In short, your `application.css` file should look something like this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require tree .
*/
```

Comment: thanks again for the detailed answer. it turns out the biggest issue was that I ran bootstrap2 code on bootstrap3 api. it was pretty painful for me to try to change the code bit by bit. but eventually the website looks usable. i still have to look into the deployment issue with heroku though